# MacBook Air Kernel Panic

Tags: macos, ssd, macbook-air, kernel-panic

**MacBook Air Early 2015 - 8GB/i5**

Recently I decided to upgrade my MacBook’s SSD and I bought the Samsung EVO 970 Plus 500GB and an NVME adapter for MacBook air.

I installed the SSD and it works perfectly under Linux (installed on this machine) but when I try to install High Sierra or Mojave I keep getting Kernel Panics.

Even when I boot from another HD and try to clone the drive, at some point it will reboot and show a Kernel Panic.

I will try to get the log file, but I remember it kept throwing some NVME error as the reason for the crash.

I am quite confident that it is something about macOS software because it wouldn’t work on Linux otherwise. A driver issue probably, or something.

Any idea on how could I solve this?

Comment: When I brought my White Tab iMac to an Apple Store in 2009 to have them swap in a much larger HD, I learned that the majority of storage devices are not supported, and that Apple has no responsibility to assist with unsupported devices.  I tried the replacement myself, and it didn't work.  Probably no driver written, and that was the end of the anecdote.

Answer (score 0):

The internal flash storage of the MacBook Air is not meant to be user-serviceable.

Apple doesn't publish any documentation about that slot.

Expecting an off-the-shelf part to work is a recipe for frustration.

That said, there are a few companies out there that have put in the hard work and built a good reputation for doing all the reverse engineering and product qualification to make reliable upgrades for some of the non-upgradeable components in Macs. The most well known is Other World Computing (OWC, https://macsales.com/). I recommend you return that Samsung flash drive and buy whatever flash storage upgrade OWC sells for your model of MacBook Air.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has released a firmware update ( https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ ), so at least for my build, the Samsung Evo 970 Plus now works under Mojave 10.14.5 as well.